# How do you make Netbeans use the signed jar-file instead of built class-files when running tests

Tags: debugging, testing, netbeans, ant, jarsigner

I am writing a test harness that wraps a signed applet in Netbeans and have written a signing step in the build.xml file (target="-post-jar") for the test harness so that it will be able to access the server as the the signed applet (using the same keystore and alias).

But when running my tests using run or debug in Netbeans the tests seem to use the class-files instead of the signed jar file.

How can I make it use the signed jar file instead. I guess it would be possible to change the classpath in build.xml or the project.properties file.

Hope someone can answer this
//Mikael

Answer (score 0):

In Project Properties->Build->Compiling, disable Compile on Save.

When "Compile on Save" is selected, NetBeans ignores the Run classpath .jars for projects and uses their compiled class files instead.

Comment: @Mikael - Answer edited. Looking at your self-answer, however, it sounds as if I misunderstood your problem statement. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the project.properties classpaths for my project and removed the class-files and added the jar instead.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, might you be able to elaborate your solution?

Comment: I don't remember My problem or my solution anymore I sorry to say.